# Showing big sized image (10GB) in asp.net

Tags: android, ios, .net

What is the best method of showing big sized image (10GB) in web page without delay, and need to zoom part of the image from user end.
Example: Family Tree Image

Comment: if you are choosing to show 10 GB image in your website, you are definitely going on wrong path. If you want to show family tree, better you make exapandable structure and not just show image of 10 GB. You will find many examples online to draw a family tree using HTML

Comment: Family tree is already designed, it is big in size and need to show this in web page. User has to zoom on particular area to view their branches.

Comment: Find a different way to do it.  Most laptops have 8-16 GB of memory.  Many mobile phones have less.  Not all of it is available to the browser, as other apps, the OS, and other tabs use memory.  And you want to take up most to all of it, and that's before decompressing (as I'm sure that's a png or jpg), so the actual size would be 2x that or more.  It won't be possible on 99% of devices out there.  Find another way.  The right way is not to make it a static image, but make it something rendered at runtime.

Comment: When you open Google Maps it doesn't downloads whole Earth map to your device. They use tiles. Just break down your big image into lots of smaller ones, like 256x256

Comment: Yes, it is the right solution. I would like to get some references for break down images into smaller ones and implement by using asp.net, android and IOS. If anybody can help please....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.